# ModuleNotFoundError while running python script via ansible

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

I am trying to run a python script from the ansible yml file but its failing with the error "ModuleNotFoundError". 
The python script runs fine when runs in the command line.
I have tried to provide the complete path of the module as well in the python script but still the answer is failure when it runs via ansible.

Error is:

```
 File \"/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1689331594.7866418-1621045-127842877821154/my_script.py\", line 8, in <module>", "    from my_module import property", "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

here are the headers for python script "/home/user/my_script.py" I am using:

```
#!/bin/env python3
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/my_module')
from my_module import property
```

and below is the ansible one:

```
-
  name: Play of file
  hosts: localhost
  strategy : free
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    -
      name: Executing python script.
      script: /home/user/my_script.py
      register: script_out
    -
        debug:
          var: script_out.stdout_linesy
```

just to add, the python script and ansible yml files both are in different directories..

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to script folder, python is not able to find the module as global one and ansible is not executing the script on that folder.

```yml
- name: Executing python script.
  script: /home/user/my_script.py
  chdir: /home/user
  register: script_out
```

Comment: not worked.. :(

Comment: And the file is on the destination server? Can you confirm doing a _ls_ ?

Comment: the ansible file, the python script and the module; all exists on the same server but under different directories...

Answer (score 0):

so after trying multiple things here and there, in ansible and in the python script.. finally one thing worked out by implying which there was even no need
of inserting or appending the path of the module, which was the mentioning the python3 path while calling the python script from the ansible..

Here is the solution to anyone who is looking for answer..
check the installed python path using
 `which python`
in my machine it was `/usr/bin/python3`.

so the updated ansible code look like this...

```
-
  name: Play of file
  hosts: localhost
  strategy : free
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    -
      name: Executing python script.
      script: /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/my_script.py
      register: script_out
    -
        debug:
          var: script_out.stdout_linesy
```